# Shell script, checking homework copy violation

Tags: shell, diff, similarity

I intend to check submited h.w answers in .c code.

does someone have link or bash shell script code that checks for file similarity (percentage of similar lines, etc...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ready-to-use-programm**
On the one hand there is a little C-programm called [Sherlock](http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~scilect/sherlock/) from the University of Sydney, which does exactly what you want: displaying the percentage of similarity. You only have to compile it yourself, but I think that won't be a problem.

**Do it yourself**
On the other hand, in case you're using a unix-based system and want to do it all by yourself there is the `comm` command:

```
compare two sorted files line by line and write to standard output: 
the lines that are common, plus the lines that are unique.
(taken from the manpage)
```

Important to notice here is that `comm` only works ony **sorted** files, so you have to sort both of them first. If you have two files, say `first.txt` and `second.txt` you can use `comm` like this:

```
comm -12 <(sort first.txt) <(sort second.txt)
```

The `-12`-option specified suppresses lines which are unique in both files, so you will only get lines appearing on both files.